# Numpy broadcasting rules when using masked_where (or do they not apply?)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mask

I would like to use broadcasting to use values from one array (lower dimension) to mask another array (higher dimension).

An example would be

```
a= np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
b= np.arange(3)
```

what I tried is

```
c=np.ma.masked_where(b[:,np.newaxis]>1, a)
```

but it fails with "`IndexError: Inconsistant[sic] shape between the condition and the input (got(3,1) and (3,3))`"

which is perplexing since broadcasting should apply here and `b` should broadcast onto `a`.
A work around is to build a temporary `d` array of the right size

```
d=np.broadcast_arrays(b[:,np.newaxis],a)[0]
```

and use it in the `masked_where` statement

```
c=np.ma.masked_where(d>1,a)
```

but this is goes against the paradigm of avoiding temp arrays by using `np.newaxis`.

OBTW, using the where command does allow broadcasting in this manner

```
c=np.where(b[:,np.newaxis]>1, 0.0, a)
```

works as expected.

Additionally,if the condition in the `masked_where` is always false, the command will execute without error...

```
c=np.ma.masked_where(b[:,np.newaxis]>5, 0.0, a)
```

will yield `a`.

FWIW, I'm using numpy 1.6.1.

Comment: the same thing happens in 1.8. Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: I can also reproduce this in 1.9.0.dev-205598b

Comment: Bear in mind that using `broadcast_arrays` in this way is actually not that bad performance-wise, since it just returns another view onto the elements of `b` rather than creating a whole new 3x3 array in memory.

Comment: Ok, on the assumption this is a bug (or undesired behavior).  I submitted the issue to the scipy mailing list, and let the developers decide.

Comment: Could you link to the archived email? Also, you might be better off submitting an issue.